# Stronger shadow on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am trying to animate a button with some glow effect.

So far this is what I got:

```
self.glowLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
self.glowLayer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)(self.currentBackgroundImage.CGImage);
self.glowLayer.opacity = 0; // set to 1 with animation.
self.glowLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor vtoPinkColor].CGColor;
self.glowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
self.glowLayer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.glowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1;
self.glowLayer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
self.glowLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[self.layer addSublayer:self.glowLayer];
```

However, I find the glow effect not strong enough. 
Of course I can change the shadow radius to make it wider but it only makes the shadow "dilute" instead of getting stronger.

[image]

How should I proceed ?

Comment: What is `[UIColor vtoPinkColor]`? Is it partially transparent already? Is your content image partially transparent in the interior of the heart shape? Try using a fully opaque shadow color and an image where the shadow-casting parts are also fully opaque.

Comment: Also try a shadow color that's "darker" (has the same hue but reduced brightness).

Comment: No; this color does not contains transparency (same as heart)

Answer (score 0):

changing the value of 
self.glowLayer.shadowOpacity  1  will work for you. 
 and also try Translucent = No

Comment: No, this does not work.
From the documentation "The value in this property must be in the range 0.0 (transparent) to 1.0 (opaque). The default value of this property is 0.0."

Comment: shadowOpacity range from 0 to 1

Comment: set self.glowLayer.translucent= NO;

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: the opacity is set to 1 later. There is no translucent property to CALayer tho.